# adding 'share this' to the bottom of orchard CMS blog posts

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Any advice on how / or where I can include the 'share this' script so I can include social sharing buttons at the bottom of my Orchard CMS blog posts. Ideally I would not use the gallery or any installer, simply just the classic implementation -- which I have done before, but I am not sure in which file I can add my script in Orchard's MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Shape Tracing](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools), to identify the different templates that build up a Blog Post. Some of those templates are shared throughout the app, so learn also about [Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates).

Look at `~/Common/Views/Parts.Common.Metadata.cshtml`
To override this view, you should copy it to your Themes `Views` folder, and modify as you wish.
If you wish to modify this template only for blog post, name your new file `Parts.Common.Metadata-BlogPost.cshtml` in the themes views folder. This is an [Alternate](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) and `BlogPost` tell Orchard to use this template only with content types that are BlogPosts.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a very simple HTML widget to do that on my own blog, since sharing is essentially a client-side thing, and it was by far the simplest option. Here's the HTML I use in that widget:

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" class="share"><img src="/media/foo/Icons/squaretwitter.svg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="Tweet this" title="Tweet this" /></a>
  <a href="https://facebook.com/sharer.php" class="share share-facebook"><img src="/media/foo/Icons/squarefacebook.svg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="Share this on Facebook" title="Share this on Facebook" /></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share" class="share"><img src="/media/foo/Icons/squaregoogleplus.svg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="Share this on Google+" title="Share this on Google+" /></a>
  <a href="https://ssl.reddit.com/submit" class="share"><img src="/media/foo/Icons/squarereddit.svg" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="Share this on Reddit" title="Share this on Reddit" /></a>
</p>
```

Notice that I'm not using a sharing script, but am using static links instead, because I want to keep the page as lean and fast-loading as possible and I think those scripts are a significant burden for little benefit. You can however if you prefer put script into an HTML widget, and it would totally work.

There are also a few ready-to-use modules on the gallery for that sort of thing, that would enable you to just add a part to the blog content type and be done with it.